# Geocoding example not working

Tags: android, geocoding

I have written a simple geocoding application but it is not working.I have given all necessary permissions.Please someone tell me where i am going wrong.Thanx in advance.

```
public class ForgeocdingActivity extends Activity {
    Geocoder gc;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final String  to_add = ed.getText().toString();    
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                try
                {
                List<Address> address2 = gc.getFromLocationName(to_add,3);

                if(address2 != null && address2.size() > 0)
                {
                         double lat1 = address2.get(0).getLatitude();
                         double lng1 = address2.get(0).getLongitude();
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Lat:"+lat1+"Lon:"+lng1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }      
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you are not initializing the Geocoder object... please post the stack trace here and you could also improve your accept rating if you want more help :)

Comment: are you testing your on a real device or on the emulator? since `Geocoder` won't work on the emulator

Comment: ya i saw your answer.It worked now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write below code for that

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentlat, currentlng, 1);
```

Now the list of Address contains the closest known areas and test this code into real device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample of Geocoding:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
  try {
        List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,long, 1);
        String address = list.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", " + list.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + ", " + list.get(0).getAddressLine(2);               
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Where "this"= activity context, "long" = longitude, "lat" = latitude

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to get latitude  and longitude from address1. then you will get latitude  and longitude from following code
List addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);